# Protractor testing ui-bootstrap-alert with dismiss-on-timeout attribute

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my protractor test I want to test for an alert which is shown when an error occurs in my app. The HTML is like this:

```
<uib-alert type="danger" dismiss-on-timeout="5000" close="closeAlert()">
    <span>Error Message</span>
</uib-alert>
```

The test code looks like this:

```
...
element(by.css('.alert-danger')).getText().then(function(text) {
  expect(text).to.equal('Error Message')
})
...
```

Protractor waits for the 5000 millisecond timeout to complete and the test fails with error message:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .alert-danger)
```

If I remove the `dismiss-on-timeout` attribute the test passes. If I set

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
```

then Protractor doesn't wait for the timeout, but the test fails with the same message.

I can solve this problem by modifying `UibAlertController` to use `$interval` rather than `$timeout` (that solution works because protractor doesn't wait for `$interval`)

So, is there a better solution? - one which doesn't require me to fork `angular-ui-bootstrap`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as Rob J says, this is a problem with Protractor, not Angular ui-bootstrap.

In case it's useful to anyone, here is my version of UibAlertController:

```
.controller('UibAlertController', ['$scope', '$attrs', '$interpolate', '$interval', function($scope, $attrs, $interpolate, $interval) {
  $scope.closeable = !!$attrs.close;

  var dismissOnTimeout = angular.isDefined($attrs.dismissOnTimeout) ? $interpolate($attrs.dismissOnTimeout)($scope.$parent) : null;

  if (dismissOnTimeout) {
    var alertInterval = $interval(function() {
      $scope.close();
      $interval.cancel(alertInterval);
    }, parseInt(dismissOnTimeout, 10));
  }
}])
```

Of course, you should also refactor the unit test alert.spec.js:

```
describe('uib-alert', function() {
  var element, scope, $compile, $templateCache, $interval;

  beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap.alert'));
  beforeEach(module('uib/template/alert/alert.html'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_, _$templateCache_, _$interval_) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
    $interval = _$interval_;

...

  it('should close automatically if dismiss-on-timeout is defined on the element', function() {
    scope.removeAlert = jasmine.createSpy();
    $compile('<uib-alert close="removeAlert()" dismiss-on-timeout="500">Default alert!</uib-alert>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    $interval.flush(1000);
    expect(scope.removeAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should not close immediately with a dynamic dismiss-on-timeout', function() {
    scope.removeAlert = jasmine.createSpy();
    scope.dismissTime = 500;
    $compile('<uib-alert close="removeAlert()" dismiss-on-timeout="{{dismissTime}}">Default alert!</uib-alert>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    $interval.flush(100);
    expect(scope.removeAlert).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    $interval.flush(500);
    expect(scope.removeAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been an ongoing discussion with regards to how protractor handles $timeout, see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/2798#issuecomment-148554704) issue on the angular-ui-bootstrap repo which references [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169#issuecomment-49078228) issue on the protractor repo.